# How to delete files selectively in Carrierwave when uploading multiple files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, carrierwave

I'm uploading multiple files with Carrierwave gem as pointed out here: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads

I can delete them all in one shot with no problem with `user.remove_photos!` being `photos` an array or json in the db; however, how do I delete selectively one or two out of the complete set of files previously uploaded?

```
@user.remove_photos!  <--- removes all the photos
@user.save    

@user.remove_photos[0]!  <--- does not work
```

By the way, I'm using `sqlite3` and in order to make it work you need to do the following tweaks:

```
rails g migration add_photos_to_users photos:string  <-- note is string
```

and in your model definition, after mounting the uploader:

```
serialize :photos, JSON
```

both, not yet shown on the Readme, although the commit was already done by rusikf here: https://github.com/rusikf/carrierwave/commit/dedc9c341e34f2e0e57d47c3eec65347fef398bd

Comment: i think there's an issue with your setup. carrierwave provided that `remove_photos!` method and should delete the photo associated to the user.  photos is just the column name but it will only contain 1 photo.  if you want to associate multiple photos to a user, create another table.

Comment: Maybe these could help you: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1704 http://bobintornado.github.io/rails/2015/12/29/Multiple-Images-Uploading-With-CarrierWave-and-PostgreSQL-Array.html#step-5-implement-remove-single-image-feature

Comment: @fabbrro thanks. You could probably gather up few words and post it as an answer. I'll accept it.